# Publishing a Filemaker database on the web

Tags: database, filemaker

I have a "large" database in filemaker on mac.
How can I export my database to my website (which currently uses in PHP and MySql)?

Comment: You'll need to do some coding.

Comment: OK  ceejayoz, could you please help me more??

Comment: Not really, no. Turning a Filemaker database into a PHP/MySQL one is going to require you to write the code for it, and to convert the data across. If you don't know how to code the PHP/MySQL, you'll need to start with some tutorials.

Comment: I know that pretty well you just tell me the steps , that will be really good for me

Comment: There aren't really any "steps" other than "write the code".

Comment: Yes that is what I am asking my friend, what code I have to write can you give me that or even a link.

Comment: We're not going to write your code for you. This isn't a "give me the code" site. It's for specific programming questions.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer friend. And one thing I will suggest that If you are not sure about any question then no need to Answer anything just for increasing credentials.  I am asking a question technical question and you are answering that "You need to do coding" Yes my friend that I know here I am for coding only and when I am asking you HOW??? then you are saying it is not a "give me the code site". As per you it should be the standard answer for all the questions on the Stack that "we need to coding" and if someone asks what? then "this is not a give me code site"

Comment: We're here to answer specific questions - "why isn't this line of code working right", for example. Very general, vague questions like this one are essentially impossible to answer here.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at the [PHP Site Assistant](http://www.filemaker.com/support/technologies/php.html), which is a part of FileMaker server. This will generate a PHP website based on your database, and the selections you make in the site assistant — even if you don't use the resulting site, it is a good way to get an example of how to access the data in your database.

Answer (score 0):

For web publishing in Filemaker, check out your options [here](http://www.filemaker.co.uk/support/technologies/web.html).

You will probably need to upgrade to Filemaker Server.

Answer (score 0):

A free service is Formgram.

Formgram converts FileMaker Pro to mobile webpages and opens up many new features that reduce data entry by reusing existing lists such as the 50 states in America, 12 months in the Gregorian calendar year, 7 music notes, 26 letters in the English alphabet, etc.

Check out a demo at https://formgram.parseapp.com/formPage?formObjectId=ejj8YHJIZy

Answer (score -1):

There is a good solution [RESTfm](http://restfm.com), now it is a open source project and you can use it like a web service between you website or any other front-end application and your Filemaker database. It uses FileMaker php Api and XML, convert it to JSON so it's very easy to fetch any data from your database.

Right now i'm using RESTfm php code to get data from my Filemaker database. For example to get all records from database `postcodes` and table postcodes u use this URI `http://demo.restfm.com/RESTfm/postcodes/layout/brief%20postcodes.json?RFMmax=2`:

```
{
"data": [
        {
            "Pcode": "7300",
            "Locality": "DEVON HILLS",
            "State": "TAS",
            "Comments": ""
        },
        {
            "Pcode": "7300",
            "Locality": "PERTH",
            "State": "TAS",
            "Comments": ""
        },
        {
            "Pcode": "7300",
            "Locality": "POWRANNA",
            "State": "TAS",
            "Comments": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

If you don't use this Filemaker database anymore, you can just write php script to fetch data from that, then save it in your MySQL database. I made in same way, got data in JSON format and saved it in to CoreData on my application.

Also u can export data into csv and just add it to MySQL database. I think it's a best approach for you.